# Max area: Quadrilateral with fixed perimeter and interior angle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, reference-request, optimization, convex-optimization

**Edit (May 1, 2018):** There appears to be an implicit assumption related to convexity in several of the answers posted thus far; see the answer and image posted [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2762240).

**So:** Let us restrict to the case in which the quadrilateral is convex.

---

My post is based on a [**tweet**](https://twitter.com/fawnpnguyen/status/982682987924832257) linking to a [**blog post**](https://jd2718.org/2018/04/06/a-maximizing-area-question/) where the following **problem** is posed:

> A [convex] quadrilateral has perimeter $60$ and a $30^{\circ}$ angle. What is the maximum possible area?

In the comments, there is a [**link**](https://www.geogebra.org/m/ZDJbE4tK) to a GeoGebra applet for exploring this problem. Tinkering with the applet led me to believe that the maximization occurs when the other three angles are each $110^{\circ}$, but I neither possess a proof that this is optimal, nor have computed the exact area (in closed form) for this case.

[image]

I would appreciate an answer that broaches the above special case, although I think it is reasonable to ask about a natural generalization for quadrilaterals; in either scenario, a proof or a link to an already existing one would be great.

**Generalization:**

> A [convex] quadrilateral has perimeter $N$ and a $d^{\circ}$ angle. What is the maximum possible area?

(So, as a well-known example, for the case in which $d = 90$, the maximum possible area occurs for a square with side-length $N/4$; therefore, the max area is $N^2/16$.)

Comment: You can restrict your parameters such that the quadrilateral is convex. If you have one angle $\theta > \pi$ radians then replacing that angle with $2\pi - \theta$ will give you a quadrilateral with the same perimeter but a larger area.

Comment: Maybe try Lagrange multipliers? $x$ coordinate of $B$ (length of $AB$ is one unknown. Length of $AD$ is another unknown. This determines where $A,B,D$ are based on your definition of $AB$ on the $x$ axis and $\angle DAB$ as the $30$ deg angle. Then the $x,y$ coordinate of $C$ are what's left. From there you can constrain the perimeter and then take the area of the two triangles $ADC$ and $ACB$ as the function to maximize.

Comment: I feel that the quadrilateral *should* be convex, or else the maximum area is non-existent, as it can approach a equilateral triangle while always increasing the area.

Comment: @JefferyOpoku-Mensah: I agree, and have edited in this assumption! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach is inspired by Jeffery Opoku-Mensah's observation that in the optimal configuration, the other three angles of the quadrilateral all equal to $110^\circ$.

To attack this problem, we will generalize it a little bit and look for conditions to achieve optimality.

- Let $n$ be any integer $\ge 3$ and $[n] = \{ 0, 1, \ldots, n - 1 \}$.
- Let $v_0, v_1, \ldots, v_{n-1}$ be the vertices of any simple $n$-gon with perimeter $p$ and area $\mathcal{A}$.
- Extend definition of $v_k$ by periodicity. For any $k = qn+r$ where $r \in [n]$, $v_k$ is an alias of $v_r$.
- Let $\ell_k$ be the length of the edge joining $v_{k-1}$ and $v_k$.
- Let $\alpha_k$ be the internal angle $\angle v_{k-1} v_k v_{k+1}$.

The problem at hand can be rephrased as.

> Given $n = 4$, $\alpha_0 = \frac{\pi}{6}$ and $p = 60$, what is the maximum value of $\mathcal{A}$?

Instead of fixing $p$ and maximize $\mathcal{A}$, it is more convenient to consider following generalization:

> Given $n$ and $m$ of the angles $\alpha_{i_1}, \alpha_{i_2}, \ldots, \alpha_{i_m}$, 
>   what are the relations among $\ell_k$, $\alpha_k$ when the ratio $\frac{\mathcal{A}}{p^2}$ is maximized?

We can divide the edges $v_{k-1}v_k$ of the $n$-gon into two groups, those that are free (i.e. both $\alpha_k$ and $\alpha_{k-1}$ are not fixed) and those don't.

For any free edge $v_{k-1}v_k$, consider following perturbation of the $n$-gon which shift $v_k$ along the line $v_{k+1}v_k$ for a small distance $\epsilon$.

$$v_j \rightarrow v_j(\epsilon) = \begin{cases} v_{k} + \frac{\epsilon}{\ell_{k+1}}(v_k - v_{k+1}), & j = k\\v_j, & j \ne k\end{cases}$$

Treating $p$ and $\mathcal{A}$ as functions of $\epsilon$. For small $\epsilon$, it is easy to verify

$$\begin{align}
p(\epsilon) &= p(0) + \epsilon( 1 + \cos\alpha_k) + O(\epsilon^2)\\
\mathcal{A}(\epsilon) &= \mathcal{A}(0) + \frac12\ell_k (\epsilon\sin\alpha_k) + O(\epsilon^2) 
\end{align}
$$

If the $n$-gon is in a configuration which maximizes the ratio $\frac{\mathcal{A}}{p^2}$, we need

$$\left.\frac{d}{d\epsilon}\frac{A(\epsilon)}{p(\epsilon)^2}\right|_{\epsilon=0} = 0
\quad\implies\quad
\frac{\ell_k\sin\alpha_k}{2\mathcal{A}} = \frac{2(1+\cos\alpha_k)}{p}
\quad\iff\quad
\frac{p\ell_k}{4\mathcal{A}} = \cot\frac{\alpha_k}{2}\tag{*1a}
$$
Similarly, if we perturb the polygon by shifting $v_{k-1}$ along the line
$v_{k-2}v_{k-1}$ for small distance $\epsilon$:

$$v_j \rightarrow v_j(\epsilon) = \begin{cases} v_{k-1} + \frac{\epsilon}{\ell_{k-1}}(v_{k-1} - v_{k-2}), & j = k-1\\v_j, & j \ne k-1\end{cases}$$

We obtain following relation
$$\frac{p\ell_k}{4\mathcal{A}} = \cot\frac{\alpha_{k-1}}{2}\tag{*1b}$$

Comparing $(*1a)$ and $(*1b)$, we conclude $\alpha_{k-1} = \alpha_{k}$ whenever the edge $v_{k-1}v_k$ is free.

In particular, if only one of the angle is given, then in order
to maximize the ratio $\frac{\mathcal{A}}{p^2}$, we need all remaining angles equal to each other.

When the edge $v_{k-1}v_k$ isn't free, above perturbations become illegal as they are changing the angles $\alpha_{k-1}$ and $\alpha_k$. Instead, we can parallel
shift the edge $v_{k-1}v_k$ outward for a distance $\epsilon$ while keeping other edges the same. If we do that, we obtain following relation which is valid for all edges.

$$\frac{p\ell_k}{4\mathcal{A}} = \frac12\left(\cot\frac{a_k}{2} + \cot\frac{a_{k-1}}{2}\right)\tag{*1c}$$
Summing over $k$, we find the maximum value of $\mathcal{A}$ satisfies:

$$\mathcal{A} = \frac{p^2}{4}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cot\frac{\alpha_k}{2}\right)^{-1}\tag{*2}$$

Apply this to the problem at hand with $v_0 = A$, we have
$$p = 60,\quad\alpha_0 = \frac{\pi}{6}\quad\text{ and }\quad\alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = \alpha_3 = \frac13(2\pi - \alpha_0) = \frac{11\pi}{18}$$
The maximum value of area equals to

$$\begin{align}\mathcal{A} 
&= \frac{p^2}{4}\left(\cot\frac{\alpha_0}{2} + 3\cot\frac{2\pi - \alpha_0}{6}\right)^{-1}
= \frac{60^2}{4}\left(\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{12}\right) + 3\cot\left(\frac{11\pi}{36}\right)\right)^{-1}\\
&\approx 154.3031702366152
\end{align}
$$

Comment: This is great! What you formalize is (I think) the strategy that I used, informally, in GeoGebra to find the maximum area: i.e., I perturbed individual vertices such that the area kept increasing, which resulted in the image in the OP. **Question** (not sure if this is obvious, or even makes sense! but I ask nevertheless): My understanding of this answer is that it involves a *local* approach of perturbing individual vertices to maximize area; if this is correct, then is it clear that the *global* max is achieved by addressing vertices one by one? Why does maximizing for each maximize for all?

Comment: @BenjaminDickman A global max is a local max. This answer essentially derives some necessary condition (but not a sufficient one) that a configuration is local max. The goal is to explain why the three angles need to equal equal to each other.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an overview of what I am about to do.

- Show that the quadrilateral must be convex.
- Prove $\triangle BCD$ must be isosceles.
- Prove $\triangle BAD$ must also be isosceles.
- Note that single variable calculus may be used to find the maximum area.
- Use calculus to show that all three other angles must be equal.

---

Clearly, $ABCD$ must be convex, as replacing changing such an angle from $\theta \mapsto 360^\circ - \theta$ preserves the perimeter, while increasing the area.

EDIT: This only works with angle $\angle BCD$. I consider the problem to be ill-defined if the quadrilateral is not convex, as in, I do not believe there is a maximum (I do not have the appropriate room or time to prove this currently).

---

Consider the ellipse $\mathcal{E}$ with foci $B, D$ containing $C$. Moving $C$ along $E$, we see that the perimeter of $ABCD$ is unchanged. The area of $ABCD$ is $[BAD] + [BCD]$, and $[BAD]$ also remains unchanged. The area of $\triangle BCD$ varies, this is 
$$[BCD] = \frac{1}{2} \cdot BD \cdot CC'$$
where $C'$ is the foot of the altitude from $C$. Clearly, $BD$ is invariant, and $CC'$ is the only varying quantity. It obtains a *maximum* when it becomes a semi-axis of $\mathcal{E}$. When this happens, $\triangle BCD$ isosceles.

---

Assume $AD > AB$. Let $E$ be on segment $\overline{AD}$ such that $AE = AB$. Furthermore, let $D'$ be the midpoint of $\overline{ED}$, and $B'$ be a point on ray $\overrightarrow{AB}$ such that $AB' = AD'$. In this way, the perimeters of $\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle AB'D'$ are equal. Also, $EBB'D'$ is an isosceles trapezoid, let the height be $h$. Then $[BB'D'] = h\cdot D'B'$ and $[BED'] = h \cdot EB$, so $[BB'D'] > [BED']$. Furthermore, $ED' = D'D$, and using the height from $B$ to line $\overline{AD}$, $[BED'] = [BD'D]$. As a result,
$$[BB'D'] > [BD'D] \implies [ABD'] + [BB'D'] > [ABD'] + [BD'D] \implies [B'AD'] > [BAD]$$
Note that $B'AD'$ was isosceles. In this way the perimeter of $ABCD$ remains constant, yet the area of $\triangle BAD$ is maximized. This happens when $\triangle BAD$ is isosceles.

---

Equipped with the knowledge that $\triangle BCD$ an $\triangle BAD$ are isosceles, Phil H's argument may suffice.

---

I am personally intrigued by the fact that the angles were all $110^\circ$. It appears using calculus on the length of the sides may not be the best tool, as there are untapped symmetries still hidden in the problem.

---

Consider $\triangle ABC$, and use the normal naming conventions. By using the sine formula twice, we obtain
$$[ABCD] = \frac{a^2\sin(2\beta) + b^2\sin(2\alpha)}{2}$$
But consider the fact that $a+b = 30$ and 
$$\frac{a}{\sin \alpha} = \frac{b}{\sin \beta}$$
Then
$$b = \frac{30\sin(\beta)}{\sin(\alpha) + \sin(\beta)}$$
and 
$$a^2 = b^2 \frac{\sin(\alpha)^2}{\sin(\beta)^2}$$
Our area becomes
$$[ABCD] = b^2 \left(\frac{\sin(\alpha)^2\sin(2\beta)+\sin(\beta)^2\sin(2\alpha)}{2\sin(\beta)^2} \right)$$
Which is 
$$\left(\frac{30\sin(\beta)}{\sin(\alpha) + \sin(\beta)}\right)^2 \left(\frac{\sin(\alpha)^2\sin(2\beta)+\sin(\beta)^2\sin(2\alpha)}{2\sin(\beta)^2} \right)$$
"reducing" to
$$\frac{450(\sin(\alpha)^2\sin(2\beta)+\sin(\beta)^2\sin(2\alpha))}{(\sin(\alpha) + \sin(\beta))^2}$$
Taking the derivative yields
$$-\frac{900\sin(\alpha)(\sin(\alpha) (\cos(\beta)\sin(2\beta)-(\sin(\beta)+\sin(\alpha))\cos(2\beta))-\sin(2\alpha)\cos(\beta)\sin(\beta))}{(\sin(\alpha)+\sin(\beta))^3}$$
Substituting $\beta = 60^\circ - \alpha/3$ gives that the derivative is zero. (I really can't bother to check further, so let's believe that it is the only extremum, and that it is a maximum).

---

**Therefore, we have arrived at the fact that all three other angles are equal. From here, computing the area is trivial. For $\alpha = 15^\circ$ the area is**

$$\frac{450\left(\frac{(\sqrt{3}-1)^2\sin(110^\circ)}{8} + \frac{\sin(110^\circ)^2}{2}\right)}{\left(\sin(110^\circ)+\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2^\frac{3}{2}}\right)^2} \approx 154.3$$

Comment: It seems important to double check that the quadrilateral *must* be convex; see the updated question.

Comment: Indeed, I saw elsewhere that if the quadrilateral is concave, we may approach an equilateral triangle, but then does the maximum actually exist?

Comment: I agree that the problem is not well-formulated without imposing a convexity condition.

Answer (score 2):

Write an expression for the area of the quadrilateral as the sum of the areas of two isosceles triangles, $ADB$ and $DCB$, as the special case such that $AD + DC = AB + BC = 30$.

Hence $AD = AB = x$ and $DC = BC = 30 - x$, which gives a formula for the area:

$$A = \sin(15)x\Big(\cos(15)x+\sqrt{(30-x)^2-(\sin(15)x)^2}\Big)$$

Setting the derivative $dA/dx = 0$ and [**solving**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx%20sin(pi%2F12)x(cos(pi%2F12)x%20%2B%20sqrt((30-x)%5E2%20-%20(sin(pi%2F12)x)%5E2))%20%3D%200) for $x$ yields:

$$x = 22.797\ldots, \text{   hence   } A = 154.303\ldots$$

For the general case, having non-symmetry about $AC$ is not optimal. What works for maximizing triangle $ADC$ will apply to triangle $ABC$.

An analysis of the previous statement follows:

For the general case, establishing a maximum area for triangle $ABD$ is key. For two sides and an included angle, the maximum area of the resulting triangle, given the sum of the two sides, say $(40)$, and the included angle $(30)$, is.........
$$A = 0.5\sqrt{x^2+(40-x)^2-(2x(40-x)cos(30))}(40-x)sin(30+sin^{-1}(\frac{sin(30)(40-x)}{\sqrt{x^2+(40-x)^2-(2x(40-x)cos(30))}}))$$
Where $0 \le x \le 20$

Note: the limited domain considers all combinations of the two adjacent side lengths.

Setting the derivative $dA/dx = 0$ and solving for x yields:

$$x = 20\ldots, \text{ hence }  A_{max} = 100$$

In summary, an isosceles triangle is optimal, and it follows therefore that back to back isosceles triangles is optimal for the general case.

Comment: A proof of symmetry being optimal would involve showing how making the triangles dissimilar (example: making the angles 14 and 16 and changing the ratio of AD to AB) reduces the area in both directions.

Comment: Good fix :) I added an analysis to show isosceles triangles are optimal for the convex solution. I'm still coming up to speed using MathJax.

Answer (score 2):

There's no requirement given that the quadrilateral must be convex.  People are assuming that the result must be convex, but that's not correct.  If the quadrilateral is concave at $D$, that cannot be switched to a convex quadrilateral without violating the constraint that the angle $A$ is $30$ degrees.

A quadrilateral with an arbitrarily short side $AD$, and with the other three sides equal in length, will have an area approaching the area of an equilateral triangle: $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} \cdot 20^2$ or about $173.21$.  This is significantly larger than any other solution proposed so far.

Below is an image from the [**linked**](https://www.geogebra.org/m/ZDJbE4tK) GeoGebra app in which $D$ is dragged towards $A$; by zooming in, one can see that the $30^{\circ}$ angle is maintained, but the result is much higher than the previously claimed maximum for convex figures.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider the quadrilateral $Q$ in the image below :

[image]

The area of $Q$ is given by 
$$
f(a,b,c,d,A,C) = \frac{a d \sin A+bc \sin C}{2}
$$

So here we want to maximize $f(a,b,c,d,A,C)$ subject to :
\begin{align*}
A &= \alpha \\
a+b+c+d &= N \\
a^2 + d^2 - 2ad \cos A &= b^2 + c^2 - 2bc \cos C
\end{align*}

*Note :  As stated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2761490/maximize-area-error-in-my-proof?noredirect=1&lq=1), the third constraint imposes that two triangles share the side BD.*

That is, we want to maximize
$$
f(a,b,c) = \frac{a (N-a-b-c) \sin \alpha +bc \sin \left( C(a,b,c)\right)}{2} 
$$
where
$$
 C(a,b,c) = \pi - \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{a^2 + (N-a-b-c)^2 - 2a(N-a-b-c) \cos \alpha - b^2 + c^2}{ - 2bc } \right)
$$

Solving $\nabla f = 0$ manually is quite challenging. With a software (e.g., Maple) and by setting $\alpha:=30^°$, $N:=60$:

```
f := (1/2)*a*d*sin(alpha)+(1/2)*b*c*sin(C) 
C := arccos((a^2+d^2-2*a*d*cos(alpha)-b^2-c^2)/(-2*b*c)) 
d := N-a-b-c   
eqns := [diff(f, a) = 0, diff(f, b) = 0, diff(f, c) = 0]  
vars := {a, b, c}  
fsolve(eval(eqns, [alpha = (1/6)*Pi, N = 60]), vars, complex)
```

$$
a = 22.79705048 \\
b = 7.202949525 \\
c = 7.202949525
$$

which yields:
$$
f(22.79705048,7.202949525,7.202949525) \approx 154.3031703
$$
We can also compute the other parameters
 \begin{align*}
C(a,b,c) &= \pi-\cos^{-1}(9.016974745-5.008487375\sqrt{3}) \approx 109.999999^{°}\\
d &= N-a-b-c \approx 22.79705048
\end{align*}

Comment: Barring some mis-calculation, it seems that your formula yields $$A(\pi/6, 60) = \frac{1}{8} \frac{60^2 \sin \frac{\pi}{6}}{\sin \frac{\pi}{6} + 1} = 150$$ which is less than the approximate $154.3$ in the GeoGebra image above.

Comment: Indeed, I have edited to correct this.

Comment: Thanks for the correction; although, as you may imagine from your approximation (and can see in the other responses) the exact value of this parameter should be $110^{\circ}$. Still, +1!